# Error: "Could not find 'cocoapods'" while installing a Pod

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

I tried to use `pod install` in my project to implement SDK but it throws this error:

> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:318:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0.a) among 35 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
>   Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/admin/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0', execute `gem env` for more information
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:327:in 'to_spec'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in 'gem'
>       from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `'

Does anyone knows what causes and how to fix it?

Comment: Try following step by step guide. http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014

Comment: I tried but even then no use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all Uninstall CocoaPods using sudo command.

Follow below steps :

1. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
2. `gem install cocoapods`
3. `pod install`

When you install again then do not use `sudo` command.
You can find for [sudo less installation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) from here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Xcode 6
2. Open Preferences
3. Click the Locations tab
4. Change the `Command Line Tools` version to `Xcode`
5. Uninstall cocoapods
   `$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
6. Uninstall xcodeproj
   `$ sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj`
7. Install xcodeproj
   `$ sudo gem install xcodeproj`
8. Install cocoapods
   `$ sudo gem install cocoapods`
9. Run `pod --version` to verify that it worked

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to update Ruby. So you should apply the following steps:

1. sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
2. **sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6**
3. gem install cocoapods

Comment: This worked. I have had cocoapods running without incident until I had recently updated to both xcode8 and ruby2.3. upvoting